# Can only apply an application_fee_amount when the PaymentIntent is attempting a direct payment

Tags: stripe-payments, elixir

I have an app that uses [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/) with `standard` accounts.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/creating-a-payments-page?destination-or-direct=direct-charges) to create a payments page. It shows we can create a Checkout Session like this (Ruby tutorial):

```rb
Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
  line_items: [{
    price: '{{PRICE_ID}}',
    quantity: 1,
  }],
  payment_intent_data: {
    application_fee_amount: 123,
  },
  mode: 'payment',
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
  cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
}, {stripe_account: '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}'})
```

My app is written in Elixir. I'm using [stripity-stripe](https://github.com/beam-community/stripity-stripe) to make Stripe requests. I'm creating a checkout session like this:

```
Stripe.Checkout.Session.create(%{
  line_items: [%{price: price_id, quantity: 1}],
  mode: :payment,
  payment_intent_data: %{application_fee_amount: 99},
  success_url: "https://localhost:4001/success"
}, stripe_account: connected_account_id)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
%Stripe.Error{
   source: :stripe,
   code: :invalid_request_error,
   request_id: "req_lsOEiRXZqPzmTs",
   extra: %{
     card_code: :parameter_missing,
     http_status: 400,
     param: :application_fee_amount,
     raw_error: %{
       "code" => "parameter_missing",
       "doc_url" => "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-missing",
       "message" => "Can only apply an application_fee_amount when the PaymentIntent is attempting a direct payment (using an OAuth key or Stripe-Account header) or destination payment (using `transfer_data[destination]`).",
       "param" => "application_fee_amount",
       "request_log_url" => "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_lsOEiRXZqPzmTs?t=1688440480",
       "type" => "invalid_request_error"
     }
   },
   message: "Can only apply an application_fee_amount when the PaymentIntent is attempting a direct payment (using an OAuth key or Stripe-Account header) or destination payment (using `transfer_data[destination]`).",
   user_message: nil
 }}
```

I've already printed the `connected_account_id` and it's correct. I double-checked it on the Stripe dashboard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the documentation is wrong or incomplete, but it looks like we need to add `payment_intent_data.transfer_data.destination` to make it work:

```
Stripe.Checkout.Session.create(%{
  line_items: [%{price: price_id, quantity: 1}],
  mode: :payment,
  payment_intent_data: %{
    application_fee_amount: 99,
    transfer_data: %{destination: connected_account_id}
  },
  success_url: "https://localhost:4001/success"
}, stripe_account: connected_account_id)
```